# Validation Loss and Validation Accuracy do not change during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I wrote a face classifier program with `Tensorflow`. In this project, first I just had 2 faces so I used `binary_crossentropy` as loss function. When I decided to add more faces I switched from `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`.

**My code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D


import pickle

pickle_in = open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Deep Learning/Yüz Tanıma/X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Deep Learning/Yüz Tanıma/y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.add(Flatten())  

model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=20,validation_split=0.3)

model.save("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Deep Learning/Yüz Tanıma/model.h5")
```

**And here is my training log:**

```
Epoch 1/20
1728/1728 [==============================] - 30s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.4833 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.4826
Epoch 2/20
1728/1728 [==============================] - 22s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.4847 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.4826
Epoch 3/20
1728/1728 [==============================] - 22s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.4827 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.4826
```

As you can see my `val_loss` and `val_accuracy` don't change. What's wrong with my code and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The answer would've been more precise if more information about the data were given.*

For starters, you've used categorical cross-entropy as your loss function and Sigmoid as activation of the last layer, which is kind of contradictory (**sigmoid means you're classifying among 2 classes and categorical cross-entropy is something you use when you've got more than 2 classes**). Either **change your loss to Binary Cross-entropy** if you want to use sigmoid (which means you've 2 classes) **or you should change your sigmoid to softmax function** if you want to classify among more than 2 classes.

Also, **you've to use flatten after the last CNN layer and before the first dense layer** (it turns the feature map (a matrix) into a vector, which is the correct input shape for dense layers.

Lastly, after doing all those you can play around with your hyperparameters (learning rate, batch_size, etc.) to see if you can get some accuracy gain.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I changed activation fucntion to softmax but it gives the same output

Comment: Then I guess a bit more information would be needed to make sure you're doing everything right, like what's the data like, how much data are you using for training, what's the ratio of data in each class, stuff like that...

Comment: I'm turning photos to numpy array, resize to 50,50 after the shuffle dumping into X.pickle and every class(face) has id number 0,1,2 in Y pickle at the same index number as photos Index numbers in X.pickle. 2 face has 12k photo but the third class has 1k photo.

Comment: Then the data seems ok to me (at least for now), did you one hot encoded your labels? as far as I know, TensorFlow expects the labels to be one-hot encoded, you may use something like this - `y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)`. Another thing is can you make your input_shape parameter value more explicit, something like - `input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2], 3)`, here "3" at the end means 3 channels (I guess your images are RGB).

Comment: I tried both. `y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)` returns massive errors. Input shape method gives same result as same

Comment: Then I guess without running the code myself, the problem can't be identified.

Comment: I solved the problem after some research I found what is hot encode and realized I need to change the last dense layers size to "my class count" because I was using softmax. I had 3 classes so I changed it to 3 and it works thank you.